# deep link from all browsers to google chrome on android

Tags: google-chrome, deep-linking

I am developing a web application which is optimize for google chrome on android.
for users who open my app with another browser,
is there a deep link to open google chrome from my website?

for example:

the following link launches the playstore application at the url indicated in the link variable

https://play.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&ddl=1&pcampaignid=web_ddl_1